# Filter HealthKit Queries to exclude entries made by your own app

Tags: ios, nspredicate, healthkit

I have an app that makes HealthKit calorie entries and runs HKStatistics queries to fetch calorie data.

Apart from manually excluding the numerical value of what I know I've written in, I can't seem to figure out a way to set up a query which only returns data from a source that isn't my own app.

Ive used predicates set up like this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateFromString:@"%K != %@", HKPredicateKeyPathSource, [HKSource defaultSource]];
```

But that raises an exception saying that a 'type 5 operator' is not allowed when querying the source key.

Have Apple intentionally made this not possible? Because using a '==' operator works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, only the "=" and "IN" operators are supported for predicates filtering HKSamples by source.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update this so that if anyone wants to do something similar...

The best way around this if you're just after statistics is to do two queries and deduct the numbers from one another.

Query 1 (ALL SAMPLES) - Query 2 (MY SAMPLES)

And then you have what you want.

Comment: This can potentially be very slow!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateFromString:@"%K != %@", HKPredicateKeyPathSource, [HKSource defaultSource]];
NSPredicate *nonPred = [NSCompoundPredicate notPredicateWithSubpredicate:pred];
```